# How to pass ToList() to Select Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In our ASP.NET Core app we want to pass `_context.TableName.ToList()` to [Select tag helper](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html#the-select-tag-helper) as follows. What should be `asp-for` and `asp-items` attribute values in Select tag helper:

**Controller**

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
    {
        private BloggingContext _context;

        public BlogsController(BloggingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Blogs.ToList());
        }
}
```

**View**

```
<Select asp-for="?????" asp-items="???">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asp-items` needs list of `SelectListItem` so you need to change your model a bit so instead of returning

```
_context.Blogs.ToList()
```

Return :

```
_context.Blogs.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Title, Text = x.Id }).ToList()
```

As you may have noticed, I am assuming that your Blog Entity has Title and Id Properties, You can use the same value for both `Value` and `Text`

Comment: Thanks for trying  to help. What do you put for `asp-for` and `asp-items` values in your example?

Comment: `asp-for` the model property that holds the selected value and `asp-items` holds the model property of `SelectListItem` list